# Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect to the `sms` page. but I see this error

> Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\tehran\cyber-security\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\RegistersUsers.php on line 36

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    session()->remove('mobile');
    $code = rand(1000,9999);
    session()->put('mobile',$data['mobile']);
    User::query()->create([
        'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        'code' => $code,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('sms');
}
```

Comment: Also, post the code where you called this method 'create()'.

Comment: Do you mean the blade file?

Comment: No, I mean controller code.

Comment: Where is the method `create()`?

Comment: How did you pass array of data to `create(array $data)` method ?

Comment: The default was Laravel. I did not create it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248142/discussion-between-js-tech-and-mahmoud-khosravi).

Comment: You must return User from create function, not redirect. Just delete last string and type return before User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RegistersUsers.php, use `register` method for redirection .

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    //...

    return redirect()->route('sms');
}
```

Comment: My problem did not solve yet, https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqgt8.png